# Access elements from a counter list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

here I'm looking for most common words inside a text. So I have 5 words found and I want to loop through each one and ask user if it's a relevant word for him, and when Y is selected make variable firstword=i

```
split_it = x.lower().split()

Count = Counter(split_it)

most_occur = Count.most_common(5)

for i in most_occur:
    answer=input('Is '+i+' a relevant word for you?\n Y or N:  ')
    if answer.upper() == 'Y':
        firstword=i

print('Selected word is: '+firstword)
```

First error I' getting is :

> answer=input('Is '+i+' a relevant word for you?\n Y or N:  ')
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

I need to convert this list to a string maybe ?

Output of most_occur = Count.most_common(5) look's like this:

> [('de', 1071), ('sellador', 480), ('para', 349), ('-', 237), ('y', 177)]

I need to access what's in between ' ' somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you want is called "tuple unpacking": `for word, cnt in most_occur:`

Tuple unpacking can also be used in assignment, like `a, b, c = the_list` or to swap two variables, like `x, y = y, x`

You also want to use `break` to stop the loop when they select one, and an `else` clause for when they don't pick a word

Putting that together, we get:

```
for word, cnt in most_occur:
    answer=input('Is '+word+' a relevant word for you?\n Y or N:  ')
    if answer.upper() == 'Y':
        firstword=word
        break
else:
    print('No word selected')
```

Answer (score 0):

`[('de', 1071), ('sellador', 480), ('para', 349), ('-', 237), ('y', 177)]`

This is list of 2-tuples, you might use unpacking as shown in sabik's answer or use `i[0]` to access 1st element of given `tuple` as follows

```
for i in most_occur:
    answer=input('Is '+i[0]+' a relevant word for you?\n Y or N:  ')
    if answer.upper() == 'Y':
        firstword=i[0]
```

Note that in `python` indexing start at 0 so `[0]` is 1st element, `[1]` is 2nd element, `[2]` is 3rd element and so on.